# How to have optional route segment for file name in Nancy

Tags: routes, nancy

I want to make a route that will match on a folder path as well as one ending with a file name. So it should match all three of these:

```
/foo
/foo/
/foo/default.asp
```

I tried these and other similar variations:

```
Get["/foo/(?:default\.asp?)"] 
Get["/foo/(?:(default\.asp)?)"] 
Get["/foo(?:/default\.asp?)"] 
Get["/foo/(?:default\.asp)?"]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be curly braced rather than paranthesis?

Answer (score 1):

In Nancy, a plain capture segment is defined in curley braces, i.e `{filename}`. You can make them optional by adding a questionmark at the end `{filename?}` and the final thing you can do it provide an optional value, that will be assigned to the *filename* capture if no value is provided `{filename?default}`